# Image appears on the wrong window on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a mysql/tkinter project and im trying to use a picture as bg for one of the windows. but instead of appearing on the new window it opens in the main window instead. I want the image to open on the new window that im currently on. **the menu() by itself works** how I intend it to but with the whole program it doesn't . any ideas on how I can fix this?

```
def menu():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("DBMS Menu Page")
    bgimage= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('960x0.jpg'))
    imglabel= Label(image=bgimage)
    imglabel.img=bgimage
    imglabel.pack()
                                
    lblmenu = tk.Label(root,text ="MENU", font=('Times New Roman',28,'bold'))
    lblmenu.place(x = 220, y = 60) 
    btninsert = tk.Button(root, text ="Insert", 
                    fg ='blue',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10)) 
    btninsert.place(x = 100, y = 135, width = 60)
    btnupdate = tk.Button(root, text ="Update", 
                    fg ='blue',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10)) 
    btnupdate.place(x = 170, y = 135, width = 60)
    btndelete = tk.Button(root, text ="Delete", 
                    fg ='blue',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10)) 
    btndelete.place(x = 240, y = 135, width = 60)
    btndisplay = tk.Button(root, text ="Display", 
                    fg ='blue',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10))
    btndisplay.place(x = 310, y = 135, width = 60)
    
   
def clearlogin():
    txtUser.delete(0,END)
    txtpass.delete(0,END)
 
def submitact(): 
    
    user = txtUser.get() 
    passw = txtpass.get() 
    print(f"The ID-pw entered by you is {user} {passw}") 
    logintodb(user, passw) 
def logintodb(user, passw):
    if passw: 
        db = mys.connect(host ="localhost", 
                                    user = user, 
                                    password = passw, 
                                    db ="1234") 
        cursor = db.cursor() 
    else: 
        db = mys.connect(host ="localhost", 
                                    user = root, 
                                    database ="1234") 
        cursor = db.cursor() 
        
    # A Table in the database 
    savequery = "show tables"
 
    try: 
        cursor.execute(savequery) 
        myresult = cursor.fetchall() 
        print("Query Excecuted succesfully")
        messagebox.showinfo("Login ", "Login Successful")
        
    except: 
        db.rollback() 
        print("Error occured") 
    menu()    


root = tk.Tk() 
root.geometry("250x150") 
root.title("DBMS Login Page") 
lbluser = tk.Label(root, text ="Username -",fg="red",font=("Times New Roman Bold", 13) ) 
lbluser.place(x = 10, y = 20) 
txtUser = tk.Entry(root, width = 35,fg="green",font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10)) 
txtUser.place(x = 100, y = 20, width = 100) 
lblpass = tk.Label(root, text ="Password -",fg="red",font=("Times New Roman Bold", 13)) 
lblpass.place(x = 10, y = 50) 
txtpass = tk.Entry(root,show="*", width = 35,fg="green",font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10)) 
txtpass.place(x = 100, y = 50, width = 100) 

 

submitbtn = tk.Button(root, text ="Login", 
                    fg ='blue', font=("Times New Roman Bold", 15),command = submitact) 
submitbtn.place(x = 30, y = 100, width = 55)
clearbtn = tk.Button(root, text ="Clear", 
                    fg ='blue', font=("Times New Roman Bold", 15),command = clearlogin) 
clearbtn.place(x = 130, y = 100, width = 55)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, you didn't specify a parent for that first Label in `menu()`, so it became a child of the (original) root window instead.  Note that you need to use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` to make additional windows - if you had put the Label in the right window, *the image would not have appeared at all*, because it's associated with a different instance of Tk.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried using toplevel() and now the "menu" comes in the original window and not the newly opened one . but I still want the "login" window open and for the "menu" to come in a new window. im relatively new to programming and tkinter so bear with me if im a little difficult

Comment: im not sure but i think you should pass in an argument to which window you want the label to appear at `imglabel= Label(root,image=bgimage)` and try using root as a `Toplevel()` window

Comment: @CoolCloud thank you so much!!! , it works now. you have no idea how long I was struggling . thank you!

Comment: ill post it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your function `menu` is the where the mistake is:

```
def menu():
    root = Toplevel()
    root.title("DBMS Menu Page")
    bgimage= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('960x0.jpg'))
    imglabel= Label(root,image=bgimage)
    imglabel.img=bgimage
    imglabel.pack()
```

You dint specify which window the image should appear at and adding it as an argument, solves the issue and saying root as `Toplevel()` is a better practice rather than calling `Tk()` which is usually just used for the main parent window only